# FFMPeg integration with xcode

Tags: cocoa, ffmpeg

I have downloaded the ffmpeg library source code using the command:
git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg

the source code contains only ".c" and ".h" files, now how to integrate ffmpeg library with my xcode project with cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a very detailed documentation on the general subject of [porting Linux apps to Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/intro/intro.html). It covers the compilation issues.

Answer (score 2):

I was building a render farm and got tired of installing and updating ffmpeg separately on each render node machine. If you want to use ffmpeg in an OS X app, you can live with the precompiled options, and you're OK with using NSTask, the easiest way I found is this:

1. Download the free app The Unarchiver if you don't already have it (available in the App Store).

2. Go to the ffmpeg site > Downloads > (Apple icon) > click "Static builds for OS X Intel 64-bit", download whichever bundle you need. This will be a file like "ffmpeg-3.0.2-2.7z".

3. Open it with The Unarchiver, will yield a UNIX file simply named "ffmpeg".

4. Drag that file into your Xcode project. When you compile, it will be in your app's main bundle.

5. Set up your NSTask, something like this (example is in Swift):

```
guard let launchPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ffmpeg", ofType: "") else { return }
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let compressTask: NSTask = NSTask()
    compressTask.launchPath = launchPath
    compressTask.arguments = [
        "-y",
        "-i", myUncompressedInputFilePath,
        "-vcodec", "libx264",
        "-b:v", "1500k",
        "-c:a", "aac",
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", // Necessary to allow playback in OS X Finder and QT Player
        myCompressedOutputFilePath
    ]
    compressTask.standardInput = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithNullDevice()
    compressTask.launch()
    compressTask.waitUntilExit()

    // Do cleanup work here if necessary.
}
```

That's it, super easy and works great. The async dispatch is optional, remove that if you want it to run synchronously, but it'll block your program's execution. You can set any options you normally can on the command line including which codecs to use, bitrates, scaling, etc. The output will show up in Xcode's debug pane as well (control how much with the "-loglevel" option).

Doing 2-pass encoding is also very easy (and makes a big difference in quality):

```
guard let launchPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ffmpeg", ofType: "") else { return }
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Make this a unique name to avoid conflicts if you have simultaneous encodings.
    let passLogFilePath = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(NSUUID().UUIDString)_passlog"

    let compressPass1: NSTask = NSTask()
    compressPass1.launchPath = launchPath
    compressPass1.arguments = [
        "-y",
        "-i", myUncompressedInputFilePath,
        "-pass", "1",
        "-passlogfile", passLogFilePath,
        "-vcodec", "libx264",
        "-b:v", "1500k",
        "-c:a", "aac",
        "-f", "mov",
        "/dev/null"
    ]
    compressPass1.standardInput = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithNullDevice()
    compressPass1.launch()
    compressPass1.waitUntilExit()

    let compressPass2: NSTask = NSTask()
    compressPass2.launchPath = launchPath
    compressPass2.arguments = [
        "-y",
        "-i", myUncompressedInputFilePath,
        "-pass", "2",
        "-passlogfile", passLogFilePath,
        "-vcodec", "libx264",
        "-b:v", "1500k",
        "-c:a", "aac",
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", // Necessary to allow playback in OS X Finder and QT Player
        myCompressedOutputFilePath
    ]

    compressPass2.standardInput = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithNullDevice()
    compressPass2.launch()
    compressPass2.waitUntilExit()

    // Clean up ffmpeg pass log files, there should be two of them.
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fm.fileExistsAtPath("\(passLogFilePath)-0.log") {
        do {
            try fm.removeItemAtPath("\(passLogFilePath)-0.log")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to remove '-0.log' file.")
        }
    }
    if fm.fileExistsAtPath("\(passLogFilePath)-0.log.mbtree") {
        do {
            try fm.removeItemAtPath("\(passLogFilePath)-0.log.mbtree")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to remove '-0.log.mbtree' file.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine on my mac machine, but on creating archive and using in other apps it doesnt work

Comment: @Swati What do you mean "using it in other apps"? If you mean "on other machines", it should work as long as you included the ffmpeg pre-built static library in your app's bundle (it should appear in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources). If the binary is not in the bundle, ffmpeg would have to be installed individually on the other machine(s). But for me, including the binary in the app archive works on other machines, even though ffmpeg is not installed on those machines. Or, did you mean you're building into a framework that is a dependency in other apps?

Comment: its misspelled, i meant macs or other machines. the binary is visible in Copy Bundle resources but when cocoa app is installed on other machines and app i try to open then sandboxing error is shown

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install ffmpeg with MacPorts(the easiest way to use linux apps on mac)

**sudo port install ffmpeg**
and then set up header and library search path in xcode project
When you install it with MacPorts then it is:
**/opt/local/include***   for header files
**/opt/local/lib***   for lib files

After all you just add includes in your code:

```
#include <avcodec.h>
#include <avformat.h>
```

Comment: Will this run FFMPEG in command line? Would the final user need to install FFMPEG too?

Comment: No, what you should do is compile ffmpeg with whatever ./configure options (to remove unused codecs for example) you need, then install it. it will manually install the .a and .h files in /usr/include/libav* and /usr/local/lib*.a, then you statically link the produced .a files into the executable that you're compiling. if you do this, the user won't have to worry about ffmpeg as it's inside your own program.