# Running an FFprobe process in Xcode to return file duration data

Tags: swift, ffmpeg

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416701/ffmpeg-integration-with-xcode/37422688#37422688), I was able to create a process to run ffmpeg from the main resource bundle of a MacOS app. The fact that I was able to get it to work, however, was really dumb luck.

But now I need to be able to do something similar with ffprobe, along the lines of [what is discussed in this post](https://superuser.com/a/1151026/1103761), to get the duration of an audio file in order to trim a set number of seconds off the end of it, using these arguments:

`ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 input.m4b`

But I don't know how to implement it. This is basically what I want to accomplish:

```
    func insertTrimArguments() {
        conversionSelection()
        if trimStartEndClipsCheckbox.state == .on {
            ffmpegArguments.insert(contentsOf: ["-ss", "00:00:02.000", /*"-t", "duration minus 4.2secs"]*/, at: 3)
        }
        else {
        }
    }
```

I haven't been coding in Swift long and processes are entirely new for me and not something that was ever covered in any of the "fundamentals" tutorials I studied before I began my project. Taking the monkey-see/monkey-do approach from the first example I linked, I can sort of make a start imitating it for my ffprobe function, but I have no idea if I'm doing it right or where to go with it from here.

This is all I have so far.

```
    // get file duration and subtract 4.2 seconds if "trim audible clips is enabled, then insert additional arguments into conversionSelection arrays
    func getFileDuration() {
        guard let ffprobePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ffprobe", ofType: "") else { return }
        do {
            let ffprobeTask: Process = Process()
            ffprobeTask.launchPath = ffprobePath
            ffprobeTask.arguments = [
                "-v", "error",
                "-show_entries",
                "format=duration", "-of",
                "compact=p=0:nk=1",
                "\(inputFilePath)"]
            ffprobeTask.standardInput = FileHandle.nullDevice
            ffprobeTask.launch()
            ffprobeTask.waitUntilExit()
        }
    }
```

How do I adapt this process so that instead of converting and outputing a new file, it returning the duration of the input file so that I can do the necessary math and include it in my arguments?