# Execute a terminal binary located under Resources with option from the UI

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to build an App that uses ffmpeg located under the resources folder of my App.

I will need to pass options from UI and run the command

could someone help me how can I call the ffmpeg?

I can get all the values from the drop down menus etc

Thank you in advance

This is the UI I'm building

[image]

Comment: Do you want to execute ffmpeg from Xcode or from your app?

Comment: I'm trying to execute ffmpeg from my app when I click Run. The command changed depending on the variables from the dropdown menus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPeg integration with xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416701/ffmpeg-integration-with-xcode)