# Xamarin Mac FFmpeg launch path not accessible

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffmpeg

I have a Xamarin Forms project with Mac support and I am trying to implement FFmpeg, so I have downloaded the Static build from its official page and added it as in the resources folder of the Mac project with the build action in Content, then I have created a service that will basically remove the audio from a video that I indicate in a path with a FFmpeg command, to do the service I have based on the following answer and I have adapted it to C #:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37422688/8496520

The problem is that when I try to execute the command I get the following error:

```
"NSInvalidArgumentException: launch path not accessible"
```

And I can't find out why this happens, I use the following code in the service (**The error occurs when calling the Launch () method of the NSTask**):

```
public void ExecuteFFmpeg()
{
    try
    {
        var launchPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("ffmpeg", ofType: "");
        var compressTask = new NSTask();
        compressTask.LaunchPath = launchPath;
        compressTask.Arguments = new string[] {
            "-i",
            "downloads/test.mp4",
            "-c",
            "copy",
            "-an",
            "nosound.mp4" };
        compressTask.StandardInput = NSFileHandle.FromNullDevice();
        compressTask.Launch();
        compressTask.WaitUntilExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `launchpath`?

Comment: @Jason It is the path of the static compilation of FFmpeg which I added in the resources folder configured with the build action in Content, that is to say in this case: "/Users/tecnopresley/FFmpegSample/FFmpegSample/FFmpegSample.MacOS/bin/Debug/FFmpegSample. MacOS.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg "

Comment: Have you tried using a different path that is not in your project resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not tied to NSTask you could use [CliWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CliWrap/) instead.

```cs
public static async ValueTask FfmpegRemoveAudio(string ffmpegPath, string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath)
{
    await Cli.Wrap(ffmpegPath).WithArguments(new[] { "-i", inputFilePath, "-c", "copy", "-an", outputFilePath }).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Beside of CliWrapper I also tested [FfmpegCore](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/runs/4011187516?check_suite_focus=true) and [FFmpget.NET](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/runs/4010659706?check_suite_focus=true) that also threw some similar exceptions like you describe. I have no glue, why they behavior different. See the complete working [POC](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/blob/ef91ba97ed1b45c688cd805e2b4d2bc89b17f3cb/GithubActionsHelloWorld/Program.cs#L64) for details.

Comment: When the console application tries to open ffmpeg the following error occurs: "ffmpeg cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified". What would be the way to make static compilations safe? do I have to notarize all static builds? what I am looking for is that the user does not have to give permissions and that it be in the most automatic way possible.

Comment: Seems like ffmpeg missed to sign their binaries and signature validation seems to be disabled on the githubactions build agents (I tested your binary https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/actions). You need to get signed ffmpeg binaries, sign it yourself, or disable the signature validation on your system... maybe that was the root cause for your initial error.

Comment: I am trying to disable signature validation on the system using CliWrapper with the command: "sudo spctl --master-disable", is there any way with CliWrapper that it is not necessary to enter the system password when entering a command with "sudo "?

Comment: Thats probably nothing for production, but on dev you need to add an /etc/sudoers entry, to disable the sodo request.

Comment: I can confirm that your code works correctly, I appreciate it. But I just have one last question, I can't find any site that distributes the ffmpeg binaries already signed, do you know of any place to get them already signed? If not, what would be the way to sign them? I have my Xamarin.Forms application signed and notarized, but these ffmpeg binaries, what would be the procedure to sign them?

Comment: I have no experience using code signing in the macos world. It seems that your not the only one struggling with signature validation and it seems that it is a moving target, depending on ffmpeg build versions and macos versions... https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static/issues/71

Comment: Back to your question: No I have no knowledge about the signing status of any macos binary available in public.